# Probability of at least t people having uncommon birthdays in a group of n peoples

Tags: probability

Say, we have n=5 peoples in a room. What is the probability that at least t=2 persons don't have common birthdays with others?

My Approach:

For 1st person: $\frac{365}{365}$

Taking 2nd one in account: $\frac{365}{365}*\frac{364}{365}$

For the rest it is $\frac{363}{365}$

So the probability is:   $\frac{365}{365}*\frac{364}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}$

Is that it? Or do I need to multiply it with ${n \choose t}$  for this example which is ${5 \choose 2}$?

So, is the probability  $\frac{365}{365}*\frac{364}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}$
 or ${5 \choose 2}\frac{365}{365}*\frac{364}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}*\frac{363}{365}$ ?

Comment: Exactly $2$ or at least $2$?

Comment: at least 2 will do

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Added as an edit

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal F:=\{1,\dots,365\}^{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}$, i.e. the set of all functions $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{1,\dots,365\}$  and let: $$\mathcal B:=\{f\in \mathcal F\mid\ f\text{ has at least }2\text{ singletons as fibers}\}$$

Then the probability is: $$\frac{|\mathcal B|}{|\mathcal F|}=365^{-5}|\mathcal B|$$

From here it is enough to find $|\mathcal B|$.

If $n$ denotes the number of singletons that serve as fiber then we discern:

- $n=5$ giving $365\times364\times363\times362\times361$ elements of $\mathcal B$.
- $n=3$ giving $\binom52\times365\times364\times363\times362$ elements of $\mathcal B$.
- $n=2$ giving $\binom53\times365\times364\times363$ elements of $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @DavidK No. The condition is: at least 2 singletons.

Comment: Right. Funny thing, when I enumerated the cases in the complement of $\mathcal B$ I remembered to include two pairs in _that_ set, where that case belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the probability that $t < 2$ instead and then subtract from $1.$

For $t=0$ there are two possibilities: all five on the same day, or two on one day and three on the other.

For $t=1$ the two possibilities are four on one day and one singleton, or two on one day, two on another, and one singleton.

Comparing these cases with the cases for $t\geq 2,$ I suspect the amount of calculation required is not much better either way.